# Dockerfile chown command cannot change the containers folder permission

Tags: php, laravel, docker, docker-compose, chown

I tried the following post.

[How to set up laravel nginx and mysql with docker compose](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-laravel-nginx-and-mysql-with-docker-compose)

But Dockerfile is not changing the permission of /var/www to www:www.

due to that all the php artisan commands are failing..

Any idea why the folder permission of container remains unchanged.

```
FROM php:7.2-fpm

# Copy composer.lock and composer.json
COPY composer.lock composer.json /var/www/

# Set working directory
WORKDIR /var/www

# Install dependencies
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
build-essential \
mariadb-client \
libpng-dev \
libjpeg62-turbo-dev \
libfreetype6-dev \
locales \
zip \
jpegoptim optipng pngquant gifsicle \
vim \
unzip \
git \
curl

# Clear cache
RUN apt-get clean && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

# Install extensions
RUN docker-php-ext-install pdo_mysql mbstring zip exif pcntl
RUN docker-php-ext-configure gd --with-gd --with-freetype-dir=/usr/include/ --with-jpeg-dir=/usr/include/ --with-png-dir=/usr/include/
RUN docker-php-ext-install gd

# Install composer
RUN curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php -- --install-dir=/usr/local/bin --filename=composer

# Add user for laravel application
RUN groupadd -g 1000 www
RUN useradd -u 1000 -ms /bin/bash -g www www

# Copy existing application directory contents
COPY . /var/www

# Copy existing application directory permissions
COPY --chown=www:www . /var/www
#RUN chown -R www:www /var/www

# Change current user to www
USER www

# Expose port 9000 and start php-fpm server
EXPOSE 9000
CMD ["php-fpm"]
```

Server Debian 9

Below line is not working as expected
    COPY --chown=www:www . /var/www

Comment: can you provide more information ?

Answer (score 0):

From the above given Dockerfile, three of your commands above the command `COPY --chown=www:www . /var/www` are actually creating the directory `/var/www` with root user as the commands in the Dockerfile is run as a root user.

The commands that are doing this are -

```
# Copy composer.lock and composer.json
COPY composer.lock composer.json /var/www/

# Set working directory
WORKDIR /var/www

# Copy existing application directory contents
COPY . /var/www
```

Once we understand that the commands are run as root, there are many ways to solve this problem in a Dockerfile. 
Follow below steps and these could be one of the ways to solve your problem.

1. Place chown in command `COPY composer.lock composer.json /var/www/`
   and give the right permission to it. Make sure you do this only
   after creating the user you want to assign the permission with to
   the folder.
2. Actually you don't even need `COPY . /var/www` command here cause
   you are using advanced copy command with chown and this will take
   care of copying all the files with the permission set in chown (www
   in your case)
3. And `WORKDIR` you can do at the end or after `COPY --chown`.